# how to blend-out a background image when scrolling down

Tags: jquery, css, background-image, fade

I have one page website on which I would like to fade out the `<body` background  on scroll down. I have tried around with `jQuery` but seem unable to find the correct selector. I can get my `<body` elements to fade but the `background-image` stays at full opacity. I've tried:

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
    $("body").css({
        'opacity': 1 - (($(this).scrollTop()) / 250)
    });
    });
```

Please see: http://inetgate.biz/ron.eggler/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to decreases the opacity of body, it meant on scroll it will hide entire content, i think you can achieve the desired effect if you create a new  div right underneath body and then put the big image on that div directly or as a background image and set the div property as absolute and 100% width height,
And then add you js like this

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
$("new div id ").css({
'opacity': 1 - (($(this).scrollTop()) / 250)
})
});
```